# Certain files give an overflow error

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro that does a calculation through a  directory and compiles the results. I also have part in here that skips corrupt or 'unreadable' Excel files, which works fine.

Now the problem is, it works most of the time, but certain files give me an overflow error. Is something wrong with my code? or is it the workbook?

with this part of my code highlighted:

```
 lrw = ws.Columns("A:Y").Find("*", , xlValues, , xlRows, xlPrevious).Row
```

here is my full code:

```
Sub StackExchange()
'added function to skip corrupt files and add the skipped to worksheet( works)
'testing more to skip other random files that arent corrupt some don't work for some reason.



Dim wb As Workbook, fileNames As Object, errCheck As Boolean 'part of loop


Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim resultSheet As Worksheet
Dim i As Long
Dim lco As Integer
Dim lrw As Integer
Dim resultRow As Integer
Dim measurement As Double

Dim wksSkipped As Worksheet
Set wksSkipped = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Skipped")


Set resultSheet = Application.ActiveSheet
resultRow = 1

'Optimize Macro Speed
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
'get user input for files to search
  Set fileNames = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
  errCheck = UserInput.FileDialogDictionary(fileNames)
  If errCheck Then Exit Sub






For Each Key In fileNames 'loop through the dictionary I added the below Sept 9, 2015




On Error Resume Next
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(fileNames(Key))
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Set wb = Nothing    ' or set a boolean error flag
End If
On Error GoTo 0    ' or your custom error handler

If wb Is Nothing Then
wksSkipped.Cells(wksSkipped.Cells(wksSkipped.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1, 1) = fileNames(Key)
Else
    Debug.Print "Successfully loaded " & fileNames(Key)
    wb.Application.Visible = False 'make it not visible


    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        If Not Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(ws.Cells) = 0 Then
            'define the range to measure
            lco = ws.Cells.Find("*", , xlValues, xlWhole, xlByColumns, xlPrevious, False).Column
            lrw = ws.Columns("A:Y").Find("*", , xlValues, , xlRows, xlPrevious).Row
            If lrw = 1 Then lrw = 2
            For i = 1 To lco
                measurement = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, i), ws.Cells(lrw, i))) / lrw
                resultSheet.Cells(resultRow, 1).Value = wb.Name
                resultSheet.Cells(resultRow, 2).Value = ws.Name
                resultSheet.Cells(resultRow, 3).Value = ws.Cells(1, i).Value
                resultSheet.Cells(resultRow, 4).Style = "Percent"
                resultSheet.Cells(resultRow, 5).Value = measurement
                resultRow = resultRow + 1
            Next
        End If
    Next
    wb.Application.Visible = True '' I added this Sept 9, 2015
    wb.Close savechanges:=False 'close the workbook do not save
    Set wb = Nothing 'release the object
    End If
Next 'End of the fileNames loop

Set fileNames = Nothing
'Message Box when tasks are completed
MsgBox "Task Complete!"

ResetSettings:
  'Reset Macro Optimization Settings
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Function Col_Letter(lngCol As Long) As String
    Dim vArr
    vArr = Split(Cells(1, lngCol).Address(True, False), "$")
    Col_Letter = vArr(0)
End Function
```

Comment: How many rows do you have? `lrw` is declared as int. Try long?

Comment: @findwindow, rows very from file to file, but the one I noticed it has one rows for the first 2 sheets, which shouldnt matter. Ill test out long.

Comment: Always use a `Long` for row variables. `Integer` can only hold up to `32767` as a positive value and there are a lot more rows than that in a worksheet!

Comment: @findwindow,worked great. Any explaination?

Comment: Wow 35 points for such an easy answer. Well, Rory and krish answered your question.

Comment: Sorry lol :( , you deserve the credit too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VBA Integer holds 2bytes and the range is –32,768 to 32,767. VBA long is the **full** Integer which holds 4bytes and the range is –2,147,483,648 to 2,147,486,647